# Block URL slug - htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using Wordpress for my website and I would like to block search engines from any URL's that have this slug http://www.trustshore.com/map-location/ and anything after that slug. I have tried searching around the site but I cannot see anyone with the same case to mine.

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Typically you would use a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file on your server to instruct search engines from indexing specific pages or sections.  Keep in mind though that it is up to the provider to enforce the directives in your robots file.  A mischievous user can index anything your webserver will serve up.

Comment: I am using 123reg for hosting. Do you think I will have access to that or know how I would do it?

Comment: If you have access to .htacces then you have access to the file system? `robots.txt` is a simple text file placed into the root of the website. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

Comment: Usually you would put such a file in your root directory.

Comment: Do you have an example I could use for a robots file?

Comment: @2ne can you read links? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

`User-agent: *
Disallow: /map-location/` on two lines

Comment: @2ne The link I posted above along with Cheery's link should give you a good start.  Also, webmaster tools from [Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster) can help you test out your robots file and give you information on what they are indexing.

Comment: Cheers guys I got it working.